# How to iterate through a DataTable in WWF?

Tags: c#, datatable, workflow-foundation

Exploring WWF I've encountered a difficulty with processing a `DataTable`. Lets say I have a table and I want to do some calculations based on the data of each of the rows from that table. To do so, I would have added a `CodeActivity` as the first step in my workflow which will read that table and populate a `DataTable`(which would be stored as a private field of the workflow) with the data. I thought that afterwards I would use the `ReplicatorActivity`(as it is suggested by MSDN as a replacement to the foreach loop) for iterating through the data and it would have another `CodeActivity` that would do all the calculations based on the row's data. The problem is that `ReplicatorActivity` can iterate only through `System.Collections.IList` but as we know `System.Data.DataTable.Rows` is of type `DataRowCollection` which implements `ICollection` and `IEnumerable` through `InternalDataCollectionBase`, but not `IList`.

- What would you suggest? Should I use a `WhileActivity` instead of `ReplicatorActivity` in this case, or some other approach?
- Should I do all the calculations in a single long running `CodeActivity`?

Comment: What about not using a DataTable in the first place? They had their place back in the early days of the framework but are pretty horrible to work with.

Comment: @DanielKelley then any suggestions what should be used instead will be very appreciated.

Comment: @Jyrkka : If the provided answer helped you please mark the answer as the correct one otherwise provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

From what you are describing a single CodeActivity can simply take care of the business. Look at the following code and construct something like below:

```
public sealed class TableManipulationActivity : CodeActivity<DataTable>
{
    [Required]
    public InArgument<DataTable> TableInArgument { get; set; }

    private DataTable _table;

    protected override DataTable Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        _table = TableInArgument.Get(context);

        // play with _table value and do whatever you want [All sorts of CRUD operations]

        var result = new DataTable(); // populate this result 

        // Manipulate result 
        // ...
        // ...

        return result;
    }
}
```

Above approach is quite easy and reusable *based on your problem description*.

Comment: Before starting to learn about building new activities, I'm trying to understand how can I use WF's built-ins, besides, the same task could be accomplished by a simple `CodeActivity` or utilizing the `WhileActivity` with an `IEnumerator` (again, stored as a private field of the workflow) to run through the table, I just tried to understand how to accomplish this using the `ReplicatorActivity`.

Comment: ReplicatorActivity Class is Obsolete in .NET 4.5 and you should no longer use it. Variables and Arguments are managed at run-time in WF 4.5 and built-in activities can access them but this was not the case with WorkFlow 3.5 in which you had to create a custom activity to copy instance data. My Advice is not to use ReplicatorActivity if you want to stick to .NET 4.5 or higher.

Comment: Currently my target is 3.5